# Not automatically downloading dropbox files when opening data in R

Tags: r, synchronization, dropbox

I recently bought a new Macbook pro (M1) and am trying to run R codes.

I open and run a R script that I have been working, but data such as csv, excel files, and RData in the dropbox are not loaded. It works only after I manually download the files in Finder, otherwise files are not automatically downloaded when trying to load in R.

Here is an example of the code and the error message

```
setwd('/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Data')
load('dta.RData')


Error in load("dta.RData") : 
  empty (zero-byte) input file
```

If I manually download the `"dta.Rata"` in finder (using Make Available Offline) and run the same code it works well.

Any solution?

Comment: What code are you using to open the Dropbox files? It's difficult to know how anyone could help you here without knowing something about your code and your file setup.

Comment: @Allan Cameron Thank you for your comment. I just added an example code

Answer (score 0):

I found that this

https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/macos-12-monterey-support

I guess we should wait until Dropbox find the solution.